# How to integrate NativeScript with Microsoft Intune?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, intune

How to integrate NativeScript with Microsoft Intune?

My project is based on NativeScript-Angular. As part of the MDM wrapping, I have to get the logged-in user information?

There are two approaches I can take 
1) Using app wrapping tool - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/app-wrapper-prepare-android
2) Tighter integration including Microsoft Intune SDK - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/app-sdk-android

I might have to go with approach where I have to call Intune MDM function to get the logged-in user.

```
MAMUserInfo info = MAMComponents.get(MAMUserInfo.class);
if (info != null) return info.getPrimaryUser();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to extend the [Android Application](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/advanced-topics/extend-application-activity#extending-application) and initiate `MAMComponents` within the `onCreate` callback.

While accessing Android native apis make sure you do it using the fully qualified name, read more on [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/metadata/accessing-packages). Also copy the necessary JAR / AAR files to `App_Resources/Android/libs` directory.

Comment: Hi Manoj, have you integrated your app with intune? If so, can you please point me to a sample "NativeScript + Angular + Intune" sample project?